# Calling a vue component into v-for

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have the following construction:

```
 <table class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
            <th scope="col">Наименование</th>
            <th scope="col">API ключ</th>
            <th scope="col"></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr v-for="adv in advertisers">
            <th scope="row">{{ adv.id }}</th>
            <td>{{ adv.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ adv.api_key }}</td>
            <td>
                <advertiser-delete-component :advertiser-id="adv.id"></advertiser-delete-component>
                <advertiser-edit-component :advertiser-id="adv.id" :advertiser-name="adv.name"></advertiser-edit-component>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Array "advertisers" keeps data from the server. Data is correct. But I see that all 'advertiser-delete-component' and 'advertiser-edit-component' have the first item of advertisers array in component props. 
Here is the code of advertiser-edit-component:

```
<script>
import { EventBus } from '../../app.js';

export default {
    mounted() {

    },
    props: ['advertiserId', 'advertiserName'],
    data: function() {
        return {
            formFields: {
                advertiserName: '',
                advertiserId: this.advertiserId,
            },
            errors: []
        }
    },
    methods: {
        submit: function (e) {
            window.axios.post('/advertiser/edit', this.formFields).then(response => {
                this.formFields.advertiserName = '';

                EventBus.$emit('reloadAdvertisersTable');

                $('#addAdvertiser').modal('hide');
            }).catch(error => {
                if (error.response.status === 422) {
                    this.errors = error.response.data.errors || [];
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The props `props: ['advertiserId', 'advertiserName']` are the same for each component call with my code. I want them to be dynamic where they take corresponding elements from the array as the loop goes through it one by one.

What did I do wrong?

UPDATE:
Here is full code of table component:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">#</th>
                <th scope="col">Наименование</th>
                <th scope="col">API ключ</th>
                <th scope="col"></th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr v-for="adv in advertisers">
                <th scope="row">{{ adv.id }}</th>
                <td>{{ adv.name }}</td>
                <td>{{ adv.api_key }}</td>
                <td>
                    <advertiser-delete-component :advertiser-id="adv.id"></advertiser-delete-component>
                    <advertiser-edit-component :advertiser-id="adv.id"
                                               :advertiser-name="adv.name"></advertiser-edit-component>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import {EventBus} from '../../app.js';

    export default {
        mounted() {
            this.getAdvertisersTable();
            EventBus.$on('reloadAdvertisersTable', this.getAdvertisersTable)
        },
        props: ['totalCountOfAdvertisers'],
        data: function () {
            return {
                advertisers: [],
            }
        },
        methods: {
            getAdvertisersTable: function () {
                window.axios.get('/advertisers/all')
                    .then(r => {
                        this.advertisers = r.data.data;
                    })
                    .catch(e => {
                        console.log(e.response.data.errors);
                    })
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: try to put :key in  <tr v-for="adv in advertisers"  :key="adv.id" >, see whether it works

Comment: I tried it (( But don't work( http://joxi.ru/krDXE3MiEndbyr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `formFields` should be array of objects like:

```
formFields: [{
    advertiserName: '',
    advertiserId: this.advertiserId,
}],
```

Comment: formFields is not important for this situation). props: ['advertiserId', 'advertiserName'], into each component call keep the same values. This is the values from the first item of advertisers array.

Comment: Could you please show created() hook method where you have populated the data?

Comment: Ok I will update my question and put all code of the table component.

Comment: Perfect, that make sense.

Comment: Can you please console.log(this.advertisers) in methods for getAdvertisersTable: function() ... I just want to understand your response, just a shape of your data, it shouldn't be real... I just need a pattern of it.

Comment: 1) console.log is here http://joxi.ru/E2p4w0qC9kjO42
2) result is here http://joxi.ru/YmExjOMT0XLZJr

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185354/discussion-between-kashif-ullah-and-aleksej-shherbak).